# Criar evento de click para vários botões C#

Tags: c#, winforms

Eu faço uma classe para gerar botões assim:

```
public Button GerarBotao(string Text, string Name)
{
    Button button = new Button();
    button.Text = Text;
    button.Name = Name;
    button.Dock = DockStyle.Top;
    button.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(100, 50);
    return button;
}
```

Agora em um Formulario (Windowns Forms) eu chamo o método para criar botões

```
for (int i = 1; i <= count; i++)
{                  
  string nomeBotão = "vaga" + i;
  string texto = "V-" + i + " LIVRE";
  p_botoes.Controls.Add(gerarBotoesVagas.GerarBotao(texto, nomeBotão));
}
```

O `count` é o número de botões que ira gerar.

Agora eu estou preso pq eu não sei como fazer para gerar a ação de click dos botões gerados. No caso o click iria levar para outro Formulário, só que com as informações do botão que seria o `nomeBotao`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Precisa ser criado um método com a seguinte assinatura:

```
private void Button_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Button clicado = (Button)sender;
    MessageBox.Show(clicado.Text);
}
```

e na hora da criação dos botões colocar esse método no [EventHandler](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.eventhandler?view=net-5.0) `Click`:

```
public Button GerarBotao(string Text, string Name)
{
    Button button = new Button();
    button.Text = Text;
    button.Name = Name;
    button.Dock = DockStyle.Top;
    button.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(100, 50);
    button.Click += Button_Click; // adicionando o evento ...
    return button;
}
```

Ao clicar no botão o evento `Button_Click` é acionado e deve ser feitas as devidas condições para esses botões criado em tempo de execução.

**Observação**: no seu código tem variáveis com acentuação e isso não é um boa prática.

Comment: Obrigado. Funcionou perfeitamente :)